# Python Blackjack Run module IDLE error?

Tags: python

I try to run the following module written for a blackjack 21 game in `Python` but get an error saying:

```
Unindent does not match any outer indentation level.
```

**Questions**

- Please help resolve the error.
- Also is there a stable option to run modules and get them checked with a `python` checker which I know there is but an easy to use one without adding code in `python` , just running it to check where the code got broken?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUNDd.jpg)

if the screenshot is unclear:

```
koloda = [6,7,8,9,10,2,3,4,11] * 4

import random
random.shuffle(koloda)


print(' Lets play blackjack, shall we? ')
count = 0


while True:
    choice = input(' Will you pick another card? y/n\n ')
    if choice == ' y ':
        current = koloda.pop()
        print(' You got a higher card %d ' %current)
        count += current
    if count > 21:
               print(' Sorry, you lost ')
           break
         elif count == 21:
              print(' Congrats, you got 21! ')
               break
     else:
           print(' You have %d points. ' %count)
     elif choice -- 'n':

           print(' You have %d points and you ended this game. ' %count)
           break

   print('See you again!')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are not used to python, in python indentation level is what matters to define blocks. Your indentations are messy. You've put an elif block after an else block. You should post this code to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentations are inconsistent. In python, you can choose how you indent blocks (e.g. tabs, 4 spaces, 3 spaces...), but you should always stick to your initial choice. Otherwise you'll get indentation errors.
Regarding your other question, there are many IDEs that will report syntax errors (such as the ones in your code) while writing. I like Pycharm, but you can choose anything you like. PyCharm also has an option to convert indentation between spaces and tabs, which can help you fix your code.